# When declaring a static array as "private" before a parallel loop is perfectly equivalent to declaring the array inside the loop?

Tags: openacc

I've encountered a situation where the code generates different results in the case of having arrays defined inside the loop on index `i` (case #1) and in the case of declaring them outside the loop on the `i` index and using the clause `private` (case #2).
Case #2 generates the same results of the code running on CPU only.

Case #1

```
  #pragma acc parallel loop
  for (j = jbeg; j <= jend; j++){
  
    #pragma acc loop 
    for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++){
      double Rc[NFLX][NFLX];
      double eta[NFLX], um[NFLX], dv[NFLX];
      double lambda[NFLX], alambda[NFLX];
      double fL[NFLX], fR[NFLX];
      .
      .
      .
    }
  }}
```

Case #2

```
  #pragma acc parallel loop
  for (j = jbeg; j <= jend; j++){

    double Rc[NFLX][NFLX];
    double eta[NFLX], um[NFLX], dv[NFLX];
    double lambda[NFLX], alambda[NFLX];
    double fL[NFLX], fR[NFLX];

    #pragma acc loop private(Rc[:NFLX][:NFLX], eta[:NFLX],  \
                             um[:NFLX], lambda[:NFLX], alambda[:NFLX], \
                             dv[:NFLX], fL[:NFLX], fR[:NFLX])
    for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++){
      .
      .
      .
    }
  }}
```

I have the following values:

```
NFLX = 8;
jbeg = 3, jend = 258;
ibeg = 3, iend = 1026;
```

In which cases the two techniques are equivalent and when it is better to choose one over the other?

This is what I see with -Minfo=accel:

case #1:

```
71, Local memory used for Rc,dv,fR,um,lambda,alambda,fL,eta
```

case #2:

```
71, Local memory used for Rc,dv,fR,lambda,alambda,fL,eta
     CUDA shared memory used for Rc,eta
     Local memory used for um
     CUDA shared memory used for um,lambda,alambda,dv,fL,fR
```

function:

```
/* ********************************************************************* */
void Roe_Solver (Data *d, timeStep *Dts, Grid *grid, RBox *box)
/*
 * Solve the Riemann problem between L/R states using a
 * Rusanov-Lax Friedrichs flux.
 *********************************************************************** */
{
  int  i, j, k;
  int  ibeg = *(box->nbeg)-1, iend = *(box->nend);
  int  jbeg = *(box->tbeg),   jend = *(box->tend);
  int  kbeg = *(box->bbeg),   kend = *(box->bend);
  int  VXn = VX1, VXt = VX2, VXb = VX3;
  int  MXn = MX1, MXt = MX2, MXb = MX3;
  int ni, nj;
  double gmm = GAMMA_EOS;
  double gmm1 = gmm - 1.0;
  double gmm1_inv  = 1.0/gmm1;
  double delta     = 1.e-7;
  double delta_inv = 1.0/delta;

  ARRAY_OFFSET (grid, ni, nj);

  INDEX_CYCLE (grid->dir, VXn, VXt, VXb);
  INDEX_CYCLE (grid->dir, MXn, MXt, MXb);

  #pragma acc parallel loop collapse(2) present(d, Dts, grid)
  for (k = kbeg; k <= kend; k++){
  for (j = jbeg; j <= jend; j++){

    long int offset = ni*(j + nj*k);

    double  * __restrict__ cmax    = &Dts->cmax     [offset];
    double  * __restrict__ SL      = &d->sweep.SL   [offset];
    double  * __restrict__ SR      = &d->sweep.SR   [offset];

    double um[NFLX];
    double fL[NFLX], fR[NFLX];

    #pragma acc loop private(um[:NFLX], fL[:NFLX], fR[:NFLX])
    for (i = ibeg; i <= iend; i++){
      int nv;
      double  scrh, vel2;
      double  a2, a, h;
      double alambda, lambda, eta;
      double s, c, hl, hr;
      double bmin, bmax, scrh1;
      double pL, pR;

      double * __restrict__ vL   = d->sweep.vL  [offset + i];
      double * __restrict__ vR   = d->sweep.vR  [offset + i];
      double * __restrict__ uL   = d->sweep.uL  [offset + i];
      double * __restrict__ uR   = d->sweep.uR  [offset + i];
      double * __restrict__ flux = d->sweep.flux[offset + i];

      double a2L = SoundSpeed2 (vL);
      double a2R = SoundSpeed2 (vR);

      PrimToCons (vL, uL);
      PrimToCons (vR, uR);

      Flux (vL, uL, fL, grid->dir);
      Flux (vR, uR, fR, grid->dir);

      pL = vL[PRS];
      pR = vR[PRS];


      s       = sqrt(vR[RHO]/vL[RHO]);
      um[RHO]  = vL[RHO]*s;
      s       = 1.0/(1.0 + s);
      c       = 1.0 - s;

      um[VX1] = s*vL[VX1] + c*vR[VX1];
      um[VX2] = s*vL[VX2] + c*vR[VX2];
      um[VX3] = s*vL[VX3] + c*vR[VX3];

      vel2 = um[VX1]*um[VX1] + um[VX2]*um[VX2] + um[VX3]*um[VX3];

      hl  = 0.5*(vL[VX1]*vL[VX1] + vL[VX2]*vL[VX2] + vL[VX3]*vL[VX3]);
      hl += a2L*gmm1_inv;

      hr = 0.5*(vR[VX1]*vR[VX1] + vR[VX2]*vR[VX2] + vR[VX3]*vR[VX3]);
      hr += a2R*gmm1_inv;

      h = s*hl + c*hr;

    /* ----------------------------------------------------
       1. the following should be  equivalent to

         scrh = dv[VX1]*dv[VX1] + dv[VX2]*dv[VX2] + dv[VX3]*dv[VX3];

         a2 = s*a2L + c*a2R + 0.5*gmm1*s*c*scrh;

         and therefore always positive.
       ---------------------------------------------------- */

      a2 = gmm1*(h - 0.5*vel2);
      a  = sqrt(a2);

    /* ----------------------------------------------------------------
       2. define non-zero components of conservative eigenvectors Rc,
          eigenvalues (lambda) and wave strenght eta = L.du
        ----------------------------------------------------------------  */

      #pragma acc loop seq
      NFLX_LOOP(nv) flux[nv] = 0.5*(fL[nv] + fR[nv]);

      /*  ---- (u - c_s)  ----  */

      SL[i] = um[VXn] - a;

      /*  ---- (u + c_s)  ----  */

      SR[i] = um[VXn] + a;

     /*  ----  get max eigenvalue  ----  */

      cmax[i] = fabs(um[VXn]) + a;

      NFLX_LOOP(nv) flux[nv] =   0.5*(fL[nv] + fR[nv]) - 0.5*cmax[i]*(uR[nv] - uL[nv]);

      #if DIMENSIONS > 1

      /* ---------------------------------------------
         3. use the HLL flux function if the interface
            lies within a strong shock.
            The effect of this switch is visible
            in the Mach reflection test.
        --------------------------------------------- */

      scrh  = fabs(vL[PRS] - vR[PRS]);
      scrh /= MIN(vL[PRS],vR[PRS]);

      if (scrh > 0.5 && (vR[VXn] < vL[VXn])){   /* -- tunable parameter -- */
        bmin = MIN(0.0, SL[i]);
        bmax = MAX(0.0, SR[i]);
        scrh1 = 1.0/(bmax - bmin);

        #pragma acc loop seq
        for (nv = 0; nv < NFLX; nv++){
          flux[nv]  = bmin*bmax*(uR[nv] - uL[nv])
                      + bmax*fL[nv] - bmin*fR[nv];
          flux[nv] *= scrh1;
        }
      }
      #endif  /* DIMENSIONS > 1 */

    } /* End loop on i */
  }} /* End loop on j,k */
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically they are equivalent, but in practice different.  What's happening is that the compiler will hoist the declaration of these arrays outside of the loops.  This is standard practice for the compiler and happens before the OpenACC directives are applied.  What should happen is that then these arrays are implicitly privatized within the scoping unit they are declared.  However the compiler doesn't currently track this so the arrays are implicitly copied into the compute region as shared arrays.  If you add the flag "-Minfo=accel", you'll see the compiler feedback messages indicating the implicit copies.

I have an open issue report requesting this support, TPR #31360, however it's been a challenge to implement so not in a released compiler as of yet.  Hence until/if we can fix the behavior, you'll need to manually hoist the declaration of these arrays and then add them to a "private" clause.

Comment: Thanks, you've been very clear. Is there a limit to the number/dimension of the arrays we declare as private? Is it safer not to have many arrays as private? For a certain test problem, even case#2 was generating wrong results and I resolved it by substituting some of the arrays with double. @Mat Colgrove

Comment: regarding your answer, I modified the question including what I see with -Minfo=accel. Even in case #1 there's not an implicit copy but in case #2 CUDA shared memory is used.
@mat

Comment: I've tested up to 13 array dimensions (which I believe is the limit in C) so effectively, no limit.  Though, non-contiguous memory (i.e. pointers of pointers) can cause extra overhead when synchronizing data between the host and device since copies need to need to be done in contiguous blocks and the runtime needs to traverse the final rows.  Hence beyond 2 or 3 dimensions, it's better to linearize the array (i.e. malloc one large block) and use computed indices.

Comment: It's not so much as the number of private arrays, it's the aggregate memory size of the arrays.  Looking at your edited question, it looks like the compiler did implicitly privatize these arrays (I should check if we fixed the hoisting issue).  So now I'm not sure why the code gets wrong answers.  "local memory" is private to a thread but stored in global memory.  This may or may not be a performance depending if the memory can be cached in L2.  In case #2, the arrays are being privatized at both the gang level (the compiler tries to put gang private data in shared memory), and vector level.

Comment: It's not necessarily safer, but I will sometimes manually privatize arrays (i.e. make them global and add extra dimensions for each loop).  The memory uses is the same, but it's easier to ensure the correct stride-1 dimension is used in the inner loop and therefore get better performance.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducing example?  Right now I'm just guessing as to the problem and it seems likely a different issue than I first thought.  If I can see the full code in context, it should help in finding the issue.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I included in the question the whole function. Unfortunately, it is difficult to include a reproducible code. The function produces different results on CPU and GPU while If I remove the #if DIMENSION > 1 part the results are the same. @mat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243019/discussion-between-steve-and-mat-colgrove).

Comment: Nothing jumps out, but given the error only occurs when DIMENSION>1, then it's likely something to do with "flux".  I tried reducing your example to something I could compile, and looked at the generated device code.  I thought maybe "flux" wasn't getting privatized correctly given it's a pointer, but at least in my example, it is.   One thing to try is adding the flag "-gpu=managed" so the CUDA driver handles the data for allocated memory.  If this works, then the problem is likely to do with how you're copying the data to the device.